# Mysql server and dynamic table name

Tags: mysql

I want to know if Mysql server support dynamic table name like this :

```
SET @tbl = 'Dawin';

INSERT INTO @tbl (col1,col2) VALUES (val1,val2);
```

because I tried all the possible syntax that I know on my query, but it failed every time.
if it is not supporting such a query, then how to solve this issue?
Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try this;)

```
SET @tbl = 'test';

SET @sql = CONCAT('INSERT INTO ', @tbl, ' (col1,col2) VALUES (val1,val2)');

PREPARE stmt FROM @sql;
EXECUTE stmt;
DEALLOCATE PREPARE stmt;
```

Comment: `WARN: No value specified for parameter 3 - SQLException`  but there is no parameter 3

Comment: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'USING @tbl;
 EXECUTE stmt;
 DEALLOCATE PREPARE stmt' at line 1

Comment: @mmad Sorry for my previous answer, it's incorrect cause table name can not be a parameter. And I've updated my answer. please check it again.